# Tox returning key error: 'PROGRAMFILES' when running DAQmxConfig.py file

Tags: python, bdd, pytest, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I am getting an error when running py.test command.
Inside the tox file, I have setup the deps to install pytest-bdd, PyDAQmx, and all other relevant installations.
My problem is that the DAQmxConfig.py file (that comes with the pydaqmx installation) fails as I think it cannot find the program files directory.
See the code here: http://pydoc.net/Python/PyDAQmx/1.3/PyDAQmx.DAQmxConfig/

**Screenshots of the errors follow:**

[image: Tox error the first time]

[image: Tox error the second time]

Comment: What is printed at the prompt when you type `set`? Which version of Windows is that?

Comment: windows 7. Set prints out heaps of environment variables ...one of which is ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tox.ini file just write the following:

```
[testenv]
setenv = 
  PROGRAMFILES = C:\Program Files
```